# How to transfer ADA in stake pool wallet?

Tags: wallet, stake-pool

I'm trying to use cntools to send ADA from my stake pool wallet to a Ledger wallet (sending "all" to address) and I've been getting:

`Command failed: transaction submit  Error: Error while submitting tx: ShelleyTxValidationError ShelleyBasedEraAlonzo (ApplyTxError [UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (UtxoFailure (ValueNotConservedUTxO (Value 0 (fromList [])) (Value 2097417169 (fromList []))))),UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (UtxoFailure (BadInputsUTxO (fromList [TxInCompact (TxId {_unTxId = SafeHash "f448b7e933fbc2bd70ee6d2dbd9bf5e4ab181cde05ee99eb3889fba48d88109b"}) 0]))))])`

I had submitted it before, but it took a long time and then said that 600 seconds for creating a block had timed out.

1. how do I see where the transaction is, and what is wrong with it?
2. is this on the blockchain or only a transaction stored to my server?
3. how do I get my ADA out of here so I can decommission my stake pool (I'm paying $200/month and haven't gotten any rewards in almost a year, time to let go of it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If during transaction submission you get an error like the one above, the TX has not been submitted and therefore isn't "anywhere". Error messages usually give a hint as to what's wrong with it.
2. Since TX submission threw back an error, it is not on chain in your mempool. It is simply an invalid and unsubmitted transaction.

Judging from the `ValueNotConservedUTxO` error message, there may be an issue where the transaction's inputs are not matching the outputs (minus the fee). Also, if the TX is submitted with a small TTL, it may expire prior to being included in a block. Both of these may or may not be due to a misconfiguration in CNTools. I am not familiar enough with CNTools to advise how to get it to work, but:

3. Since your needs are relatively simple (emptying a wallet containing a single UTXO and deregistering a pool), I recommend using raw `cardano-cli` commands for a fine, low-level control over your workflow. This way, you can customize the TTL, as well as exactly which assets you're sending to the new wallet and where the fees will be paid from. You can also create and submit a pool deregistration certificate with cardano-cli.

Let me know if you need further clarification on how to do all this with cardano-cli. [CoinCashew's Guide](https://www.coincashew.com/coins/overview-ada/guide-how-to-build-a-haskell-stakepool-node/part-iv-administration/retiring-your-stake-pool) is an excellent resource for this if you need help.

Comment: Literally the first command: "Command failed: query protocol-parameters   Error: /params.json: /params.json: openBinaryFile: permission denied (Permission denied)"

Comment: (I keep having problems with anything related to Cardano, not sure why it's so difficult)

Comment: No worries! Its almost always the obvious and most silliest of things!